# Elasticsearch: Query nested array

Tags: elasticsearch, e-commerce, elastic-stack, bigcommerce, product-variations

I'm trying to write multi-fields queries for searching function, but there are some problems with full-text search in nested array

My data has format like this:

```
{
  "name": "[Sample] AAA",
  "variant": [
    ["s", "black"],
    ["l", "white"],
  ],
},
{
  "name": "[Sample] BBB",
  "variant": [
    ["s", "white"],
    ["l", "black"],
  ],
},
```

With input `sample s black` or `sample black s`, I'd like to find all documents having exact `s` and `black` options like `[Sample] AAA` but not `[Sample] BBB`. I've tried `nested` query but didn't get the desired result. Is there any way to refactor the data format and write the optimal mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Create the Index with the following mappings

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "variant": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "0": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "1": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- Put the sample documents

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "name": "[Sample] AAA",
  "variant": [
    ["s", "black"],
    ["l", "white"],
  ]
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
  "name": "[Sample] BBB",
  "variant": [
    ["s", "white"],
    ["l", "black"],
  ]
}
```

- GET the docs

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "variant",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "variant.key": "s"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "variant.value": "black"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'm looking for a query like`query: "sample s black"`. Is there any way to restructure the data format to make it easier to query?